# Is it safe to use pygame in a thread or a process?

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame, multiprocessing

I need to use pygame in another thread, that is, the pygame loop and all the rendering on a seperate thread. I can't use pygame in the main thread.

I heard that some environments don't like that rendering is done outside of the main thread, but I couldn't find any confirmation or examples online.

So, is it safe to run pygame on a seperate thread? If not, is it safe to use pygame on a seperate process, instead? if not, what alternatives do I have?

Just to be clear, I want to do something like this:

```py
from threading import Thread  # should I use multiprocessing.Process?

import pygame as pg


def run_game():
    pg.init()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode(...)
    running = True
    while running:
        # all pygame event handling and logic
        pg.dispaly.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Thread(target=run_game, args=())  # should be Process?
    t.start()
    # do other things on the main thread
    t.join()
```

On my machine (Windows 10, Python 3.7.9) this example works perfectly fine, and it also works with `multiprocessing.Process` instead of `threading.Thread`. I don't know if it will work on all platforms, and if a more complicated example would work on my machine.

So, is it safe, or do I need to do something different to make this work?

Comment: "I can't use pygame in the main thread" - Why?

Comment: You can use pygame in only one tread, but that thread is not necessarily the main thread

Comment: @mousetail Can you show a confirmation for this? I heard that some environments don't like pygame outside of the main thread.

Comment: You know it works on windows because you tested it there. In linux there is no real concept of a "main thread" since they are really all seperate processes that share a TGID. However, the POSIX standard does allow for different treatment of main and other threads so behavior might be different on Solaris or FreeBSD

Comment: @mousetail Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970612/pygame-in-a-thread) for example. From what I see in this question, Pygame doesn’t play nice with threading, which is why I am looking for a confirmation or an example of correct usage of pygame with threading/multiprocessing.

Comment: I can only confirm how the threading works for windows and linux. If your program should also work on mac, perhaps starting a process would be safer